# '%NODE_ENV%' === 'production' evaluate to false when `%NODE_ENV%` value is `production`

Tags: react-scripts, rollbar

I'm following this guide https://docs.rollbar.com/docs/react#section-create-react-app and encounter unexpected behavior:

Inside `/public/index.html`:

```
var env = '%NODE_ENV%'
console.log(1:, ('%NODE_ENV%' === 'production'))
console.log(2:, '%NODE_ENV%')
console.log(3:, env)
console.log(4:, (env === 'production'))
```

output:

```
1: false
2: "production"
3: "production"
4: true
```

Why the first log is `false`?

I'm on `react-scripts@2.1.8`

Answer (score 0):

tl:dr;

```
var env = '%NODE_ENV%';
var _rollbarConfig = {
    enabled: (env === "production")
```

This issue was bizarre. The compiled code ended up like this with Rollbar's documentation:

*public/index.html:*
`enabled: ("%NODE_ENV%" === "production"),`

*build/index.html:*
`enabled: !1`

Adding another `!` in front of the evaluation gave the correct answer, but was bizarre. So I thought about capturing the variable before hand in `env` and evaluating that variable for "production", which worked out:

*public/index.html*

```
var env = '%NODE_ENV%';
var _rollbarConfig = {
    enabled: (env === "production")
```

*build/index.html*

```
var env = "production";
var _rollbarConfig = {
    enabled: env === "production"
```

It now evaluates correctly, and is better for future maintenance.